# Co-worker for got to do 'git-pull --rebase' after a filter branch, lots of duplicates

Tags: git

I ran a `git filter-branch` to fix some issues with our repository and mailed out to my co-worker to make sure he did a `git pull --rebase`.  It appears that he forgot to do that and then continued to work for another.

This is how things look:

- master:  let's assume it has all of the "right" commits
- mybranch:  a bunch of commits that all match with master
- hisbranch: a bunch of commits where the hashes match nothing

What should I do to "fix" this?  I don't want to lose his commits that he made to `hisbranch` after he forgot to do "git pull --rebase" yet I don't want to have duplicate commits.  No matter if I merge `mybranch --> hisbranch` or `hisbranch --> mybranch` I get duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR summary: if repeating your `git filter-branch` produces what you want (and it probably does), you just need to get him to do it too now—or to take your updated repository and stop using his non-filtered one.

#### Long theory-based description below (which you can ignore if you like)

What `filter-branch` does (because it must: this is true for `git rebase` and even `git commit --amend` as well) is to *copy* commits, with some change or changes applied just before making the *new* commits.

When you ran `git filter-branch` you *copied* some or all of your repository, starting from the first change made.  (If you make the *exact same* commit, including the same user names and time stamps, you get the original commit back.  But if you change anything, including a parent-ID, you get a different commit.)

Let's say that your repository has one hundred commits, and you applied your filter to all of them, but it did nothing to the first 75, then touched the 76th.  The first 75 "copies" were 100% identical to their originals and thus git simply re-used the originals.  But on the 76th, your filter did something—perhaps removing a sensitive file, perhaps just fixing the spelling of the commit author's name, but *something* was different.  So this made a new commit with a new SHA-1 ID.  After that, the 77th commit might have been the same as its original, except for one problem: it had to list the "new" commit-number-76 as its parent, not the old one.  So the copy of #77 was also changed and had a new SHA-1 ID, and so on.

After filtering, you then threw away your originals and kept only your copies.  (Since 75 of your copies are actually the "original originals" as it were, you really only threw away 25 commits.  Obviously the actual numbers will change depending on how far back in history your filter made changes—and on how many commits you have in your repository—but this should give you the tools to think about it all.)

Your co-worker, meanwhile, had the same 100 commits you had, at that time.  He then added a new 101st commit, on branch `hisbranch`.  That commit has, as its parent, the *original* commit #100, which has as its parent the *original* commit #99, and so on back to commit #76.

If he gives his repository's contents back to you (e.g., via `git push`), he will *restore* to your repository the commits you threw away.  As far as git is concerned, those commits are all stuff you both want: he has it in his history, and he's giving you his history, so you get it all.

You could weed it out of your repository again, but the next time he gives you his stuff, you'll just get it all back again.  You must have *him* weed it out of *his* repository.  (You can duplicate his weed-out work in yours but if you set this up carefully, you won't have to.)

What he (or you) needs to do is:

1. take notice of the fact that you've "rewritten history"
2. figure out what part of his work is uniquely his, and what part sits atop the history you've rewritten
3. move "his work" from being based on the *original* (pre-rewrite) history, to being based onto the *new* (post-rewrite) history.

An ordinary `rebase` might not do the trick because that looks for a common shared history, based on the commit graph.  When you rewrote your history, you threw out (some of) the history that would otherwise be shared.  Once the two of you re-synchronized, he brought it back:

```
                       x--x--x   <-- his additions
                      /
          o--o--...--o   <-- before rewriting
         /         `-o   <-- maybe more branches
...--o--*
         \
          o--o--...--o   <-- after rewriting
                   `-o   <-- similar more branches
```

He has (or had) the "before" copy and not the "after"; you had the "after" and not the "before" (assuming you cleaned up the "originals" that filter-branch leaves behind).  Then, after he pushed his `x` commits, you have both, including his `x` commits.

What you *want* looks more like this:

```
...--o--*              x--x--x   <-- his additions
         \            /
          o--o--...--o   <-- after rewriting
                   `-o   <-- similar more branches
```

Note that the parent of the first `x` is some post-rewrite commit.  A regular (plain) `rebase` will attempt to find some shared history, and that's likely to start at commit `*` instead and follow the pre-rewrite history, so it is likely to attempt to replay (copy) lots of unwanted commits.

It should be possible for him to use the new `--fork-point` stuff to locate which commits are "purely his", and which are consequences of history-rewriting.

It may also be possible for him (or you) to run (or re-run) your `fiter-branch`, and that may be the easiest way to deal with this—especially since you both now have the doubled-up history.  (This requires a deterministic filter, but it's virtually certain you're using one.)

If you re-run your filter-branch on the doubled-up history, you'll turn this:

```
                       x--x--x   <-- his additions
                      /
          o--o--...--o   <-- before rewriting
         /         `-o   <-- maybe more branches
...--o--*
         \
          o--o--...--o   <-- after rewriting
                   `-o   <-- similar more branches
```

into this:

```
                       x--x--x   <-- his additions
                      /
          o--o--...--o   <-- before rewriting
         /         `-o   <-- maybe more branches
...--o--*              x--x--x   <-- his additions, rewritten
         \            /
          o--o--...--o   <-- after rewriting
                   `-o   <-- similar more branches
```

Now all *you* have to do is throw out the "pre-rewrite" commits (everything above the center line of the resulting commit graph, as it were), which is what you get when you remove all the `refs/originals/` references.

The tricky bit is that he must now take your rewrite (or repeat it exactly on his side), so that he throws out the old (pre-rewrite) commits.  One easy way for him to do that is to clone your updated repository, assuming he has not yet made any new commits that you didn't just rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I can just re-run the filter branch and it'll re-write his directory again (in the same way), resync'ing all of our commits and hashes

Comment: You still need to get him to do something.  Working on answer now.